# pandas dataframe- how to find words that repeat in each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a text column containing long string values. The text has been cleaned and has only words as shown in the example below.

```
text
=====
This is the first row
This is the second row
third row this is the
```

I would like to get this content:

```
text
=====
first
second
third
```

How do I remove the words that appear in each row of a dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['This is the first row','This is the second row', 'third row this is the']})

# what next?
```

Comment: you want to capture the 4th word?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: no...I want to remove words that appear in each row. For example, "This" can be found in each row.

Comment: Does your non repeating word appear exactly at the same position in every row? (eg< 4th word in each row is non repeating)

Comment: No, they can be anywhere. I see that in my example I have put it accidentally at the same (4th) place. I have changed the initial example. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem yourself before asking? If so, can you post this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the dataframe to a string, then you can do something like this:

```
text = 'This is the first row, This is the second row, This is the third row'
arr = [set(x.split()) for x in text.split(',')]
mutual_words = set.intersection(*arr)
result = [list(x.difference(mutual_words)) for x in arr]
result = sum(result, [])
final_text = (", ").join(result)
print(final_text)
# 'first, second, third'
```