# Pandas dataframe - how to eliminate duplicate words in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'category':[0,1,2],
                   'text': ['this is some text for the first row',
                            'second row has this text',
                            'third row this is the text']})
df.head()
```

I would like to get the following result (without words repeating in each row):

Expected result (for the example above):

```
category     text
0            is some for the first
1            second has
2            third is the
```

With the following code I tried to get all data in rows to a string:

```
final_list =[]
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    # Create list for the current row
    my_list =rows.text
    # append the list to the final list
    final_list.append(my_list)
# Print the list
print(final_list)
text=''

for i in range(len(final_list)):
    text+=final_list[i]+', '

print(text)
```

The idea in this question ([pandas dataframe- how to find words that repeat in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086312/pandas-dataframe-how-to-find-words-that-repeat-in-each-row)) does not help me to get the expected result.

```
arr = [set(x.split()) for x in text.split(',')]
mutual_words = set.intersection(*arr)
result = [list(x.difference(mutual_words)) for x in arr]
result = sum(result, [])
final_text = (", ").join(result)
print(final_text)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get it?

Comment: this sounds like an [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) problem. Why would you do that?

Comment: I need these unique values for further NLP processing

Comment: Actually, you are just removing `this`, `the` and `row` to obtain your desired output.

Comment: Your expected result removes all copies of words that occur in more than one column, but it has "the" repeated in row 0 and row 2. How do you determine if you should keep a word or not?

Comment: this above is just an example. It's not just about this, the and row. My original dataframe has about 20.000 words.

Comment: it seems you are going to use bag of words approach and at some point you'll have an array of indicator variables. It will be **a lot** easier to remove frequent words at that point than at the preprocessing step

Comment: @Craig target words are those which appear in every row.

Comment: @Marat I have no access to previous data. My entry point is this dataframe and I have to find duplicates in it.

Comment: I do not see how this last comment relates to the question or my comment. You don't need access to previous data, I'm saying that in future processing you will transform the text to indicators of vocabulary items, and at that point filtering out common words will be almost trivial

Comment: @Marat thank you for the comment. However, I would like to solve it in this dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.split` to split the column `text` around the delimiter space then use `reduce` to get the intersection of the words found in all the rows, finally use `str.replace` to remove the common words:

```
from functools import reduce

w = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), df['text'].str.split())
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(rf"(\s*)(?:{'|'.join(w)})\s*", r'\1').str.strip()
```

---

```
   category                    text
0         0   is some for the first
1         1              second has
2         2            third is the
```